# Hopper Disassembler v4, Cannot launch debugger. Not Found LLDB

Tags: lldb, disassembly, hopper

I run Hopper Disassembler v4 Debugger execute a program, but tooltip Cannot Launch debugger.  Detail Error Content is:

> "Please make sure that LLDB is installed, and that the binary can be
>   launched on the targeted computer."

I am Macos 10.14.6, haved lldb,version is lldb-1100.0.30.12 in `/usr/bin/lldb`

Comment: Did you make sure the app runs under lldb?  Just try, in Terminal, `lldb YourApp.app` and then `run` at the lldb prompt.  A lot of apps can't be debugged - they mark themselves as non-debuggable and the system respects that marking by refusing to allow the debugger to attach.  The particular app you are trying to debug might be one of these.  You'll see the error from `run` if this is the case.